# Saving prediction model without saving the original dataset

Tags: r, save

I would like to save my model for external replication.
I use the code below to train the model and save it.

```
F10y<-  glm(F10 ~    age + sex + bmi, data=discovery1, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(F10y)
save(F10y, file = "F10y1.rda")
```

When I load the model, I can also see the original data set on which the data is build (discovery1 in this example). Due to privacy, I want to save the model but without the possibility to see this original data set.

Is this possible?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the rownames of your data to just indices as these show up on the resulting model. Then after the model is created, set the `$data` and `$model` element to null.

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars
rownames(my_mtcars) <- seq(1,nrow(my_mtcars))
model <- glm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = my_mtcars)
model$data <- NULL
model$model <- NULL
predict(model,data=mtcars)
```

Comment: Thank you  @Ian Campbell, is there also a way that also this is nowhere visible? i.e. no data set information at all.